# c++ passing a const object reference to a function

Tags: c++, reference, constants

> error: passing 'const QByteArray' as 'this' argument of 'QByteArray& QByteArray::append(const QByteArray&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

since it is a convention to make objects const while passing as function arguments i have done it.
but now i am getting an error!!,
i dnt want to make the function constant as i have to convert data in qbyte array into short and then append it another array.

```
QByteArray ba((const char*)m_output.data(), sizeof(ushort));
    playbackBuffer.append(ba);
```

I really need to pass this array into `playbackbuffer`;
It is giving me an error on `playbackBuffer.append(ba)`;

please help
thanks in advance

Comment: You will atleast have to post some code to make sense of the error, Don't you think so?

Comment: The convention should be that you pass object by const reference *if they are not meant to be changed*.  If the passed QByteArray shouldn't be changed, then you can copy it to a local QByteArray and work on that one.

Comment: "since it is a convention to make objects const while passing as function arguments" - only if the function isn't supposed to modify it. If it does modify it, then declaring it `const` is misleading at best.

Comment: sorry for that will post the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 'const' as ' this ' argument of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328320/passing-const-as-this-argument-of)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This means you are calling a non-const member function on a const member. Presumably, your `append` function modifies the byte array. With a const reference, you shouldn't be modifying.

Comment: i am not modifying data from array im only reading it and appending it into another array,is'nt there a way around.

Comment: From your edited question: it is playbackBuffer that may not be const.  Don't pass it as const reference if it needs to be filled in.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what it says is that you're trying to append to a constant array.

If "append" does not change the object itself but just returns the two arrays appended, [the method needs to be declared const to allow the call.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Methods)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar();
};

const foo f;
f.bar();
```

Here, in the call to `bar()`, the `this` pointer is `&f`. But `bar()` is not a const-function, so the type of `this` is `foo*`, which is incompatible with `const foo*`. (In other words, `bar()` says it might mutate the `foo`, but `f` says it's a non-mutable`foo`.)

Either `bar()` needs to be marked as `const` (if it can), or `f` needs to not be `const`.

In your case, I'm going to assume you're using Qt and so cannot modify `QByteArray` (nor should you, since `append` is necessarily a non-const function), and instead suggest you get rid of the `const` on the object, which is preventing you from using the function.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to call a non const function on a const object?
That's what passing a const xxx as 'this' argument would mean.
Since ultimately any member function really is
(Class * this, rest of arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Either make your

```
QByteArray& QByteArray::append(const QByteArray&);
```

be

```
QByteArray& QByteArray::append(const QByteArray&) const;
```

(highly unlikely to solve anything) or just

```
    QByteArray* pObj = const_cast<QByteArray*>(&your_obj)
    if (pObj)
        pObj->append(...
```

Comment: Dangerously close to -1'ing, but why would you suggest a `const_cast` here? Do you want undefined behavior?

Comment: Indeed, `const_cast` is completely wrong, and will give undefined behaviour if the object is `const`. If you need to be able to modify it, then don't declare it `const` in the first place.

Comment: No, this is worse: only dynamic_cast returns a null pointer when it can't cast.

Comment: depends on compiler. They don't all follow the standards