# typecast array of shorts into bytearray

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I am trying to convert a short array into a bytearray in qt.
is there any function available to do the casting.
if i have to use const char * for conversion how should i do it.
and is there any better way than to use reinterpret cast

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ passing a const object reference to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327437/c-passing-a-const-object-reference-to-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an array of short to bytes simply by casting a byte pointer to the short array

```
short s[10];
unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(s);
```

then use the pointer to go through all the bytes in the array where you copy the `*p` to a byte array if u wish.

```
for ( unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(s); 
      p < s + sizeof(s); 
      ++p)
{...}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` to do this, but be aware that you are making your code very architecture specific. Use of `reinterpret_cast` doesn't exactly guarantee your code is wrong, but it should be ringing warning bells.

If what you want to do is, given an array of shorts, produce an array of bytes with the same values, you probably want this:

```
void copy(char *to_byte_array, short const *from_short_array, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos != size; ++pos)
    {
         to_byte_array[pos] = from_short_array[pos];
    }
}
```

if you use reinterpret_cast, your short array containing say 20, 30, 40, will look like an array of chars containing 0, 20, 0, 30, 0, 40 (or possibly 20, 0, 30, 0, 40, 0, depending on architecture).

Comment: its throwing error "invalid conversion from short int to const char *"

Comment: i doubt it's throwing that. That sounds more like a compiler error. I'd imagine you had the parameters at the call back to front