# passing 'const' as ' this ' argument of

Tags: c++, constants, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ passing a const object reference to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327437/c-passing-a-const-object-reference-to-a-function)

```
void SpectrumAnalyserThread::calculateFFT(AnalogData &frame, const QByteArray       &playbackBuffer)   
{

   fft->window(frame.data(),frame.size());

    fft->fix_fftr(frame.data(), qFloor(log(frame.size()) / log(2)), 0);

     for(int i = 0; i < m_numSamples; ++i)
     {
        m_output.push_back(frame[i]);
     }
     fft->fix_fftr(m_output.data(), qFloor(log(m_output.size()) / log(2)), 0);

    const QByteArray ba((const char*)m_output.data(), sizeof(ushort));

    const_cast<QByteArray &>(playbackBuffer);

    playbackBuffer.append(ba);

    m_output.clear();

    calculateMagnitude(frame);

}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: passing 'const QByteArray' as 'this' argument of 'QByteArray& QByteArray::append(const QByteArray&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

If I make the function const then it throws errors at
`m_output.clear()`, `m_output.push_back()`, which is obvious but I need to clear the buffer so that when the function is called again previous data does not get appended.

Comment: you may want to preview your question next time when asking.

Comment: `const_cast<QByteArray &>(playbackBuffer);` ??

Comment: @yi_H: That's a cruel recommendation. If the referencee was declared const, you invite undefined behaviour. Don't band-aid the sympton, but fix the problem. And who the f*** did upvote `const_cast`ing?

Comment: @phresnel: huh? that's a lot of nonsense for one comment: i didn't recommend anything. that's one of his lines. and it's not UB...

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question? The answer is the same - if you want to modify something, then don't declare it `const`.

Comment: @yi_H: a) Beg your pardon. However, your comment in itself is not unambiguous. `??` is often used as the "huh, solution is obvious, dude"-operator. b) It is nonsense to proclaim that I said it's UB.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify `playbackBuffer` then you should take the parameter as a non-`const` parameter:

```
QByteArray &playbackBuffer
```

This is completely independent of whether the member function of `SpectrumAnalyserThread` is declared `const` (which it shouldn't be if it modifies `this`' internal state).

---

Note that this line has no effect. To use the result of a cast you must do something with it. A statement that is a cast alone just performs the conversion and then throws the result of that conversion away.

```
const_cast<QByteArray &>(playbackBuffer);
```

---

You could do something like below but it risks undefined behaviour and is an abuse of the contract you have with callers of your function where you say, by taking a `const` reference, that you're not going to modify `playbackBuffer`.

```
const_cast<QByteArray &>(playbackBuffer).append(ba);
```

Comment: you saved the day thanks a ton

Answer (score 4):

The problem is at

```
playbackBuffer.append(ba);
```

You want to mutate `playbackBuffer`, so don't pass it as a const reference.

Answer (score 0):

[const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) returned an object of type `QByteArray&` (it wiped off `const` from the original type) but you didn't do anything with that object - the type of the `playbackBuffer` didn't change - it remained `const QByteArray&`.

You can do two things:

1) call class method on a temporary unnamed variable of type `QByteArray&` returned by the cast operator:

```
const_cast<QByteArray &>(playbackBuffer).append(ba);
```

2) assign return value of the cast operator to the local variable of type `QByteArray&` (if you want to use it again to call non-const member functions):

```
   QByteArray& playbackBufferNonConstRef = const_cast<QByteArray&>(playbackBuffer);
   playbackBufferNonConstRef.append(ba);
```

Regardless of this, you should first think of why passing an object as a const reference and then trying to trick it and change it after casting `const` away. If you declare function's argument as a const reference, your clients will believe that object passed to it won't be changed. But with this design they'll be getting unexpected results...